# Sphere object does not rotate

Tags: three.js

I have a THREE.JS scene where there's a plane geometry in the middle of the scene. The plane geometry has a camera added to it. I also am using this example http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_lightmap.html  to add a lightmap and am adding it to my plane geometry.

Psuedocode:

```
planeGeometry.add(camera);
planeGeometry.add(sphereGeometryLightMap);
```

The problem is that when I try to rotate the sphere geometry on any axis, nothing happens. I tried using `.rotation` and setting the `matrix4`. Why is it that I can't rotate this sphere object when added to another object? How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the camera to the `planeGeometry`.

Also I assume that `sphereGeometryLightMap` is of type THREE.Mesh in which case you need to add it to the scene. Not to the `planeGeometry`.

If you want the `sphereGeometry` relative to the `planeGeometry` you can do:

```
var object = new THREE.Object3D();
object.add (planeGeometry);
object.add (sphereGeometry);
```

Before you add the `geometries` to the `object` you position them relative as you want.
Then, instead of modifying the `planeGeometry`, you modify the `object`.

Comment: I wanted the sphere to always be in reference of the planeGeometry. The plane geometry constantly moves around.

Comment: I get the same result, I'm unable to rotate the spheregeometry at all.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Here's the fiddle. Try to modify the rotation of the sphere. http://jsfiddle.net/6uqvzsco/